# Asp.net C# List events in editor

Tags: c#, asp.net

In VB.net I can see all the events an asp.net object has in the drop downs. In c# I cannot. How can I see all the events associated with object in question.

For example, I have an asp button, I cannot see any event in the editor. If I switch to design mode and double click on the button I get 1 event created, but sometimes I would like to see all event that are possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for something like intellisense, i.e. button.*ListEvents* so that you can all the events associated with the control.  Sorry I don't have enough points to ask in a comment to answer you more specifically.
If you're not getting intellisense in your markup, which you should by typing 'on*Event*'.  The on will drop you down to the events and then you'll have to add the event to your class.  If you're not seeing what you want you can go to MSDN to get a complete list of events, for a button https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button_events(v=vs.110).aspx or if you want to create your own you can do that too.

Comment: You can also when in Design mode select the control and click the lighting bolt in the properties toolbar.  The lighting bolt button will display the events associated with that control.

Comment: Yup, that's it thanks, the lighting bolt only appears in design mode, thank you